# Different function offset for same libc version

Tags: glibc

This is for a pwnage challenge. I have two virtual machines. Both are running glibc 2.19. But, when I analyze the function offset in both, it is different in both of them.

As per my knowledge, same version libc have same offsets. I searched over net but didn't find any convincing resolution. Below are the details on two machines:

Machine 1:

```
~$ objdump -d /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep system
00040190 <__libc_system>:

~$ objdump -d /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep "IO_puts>"
00065650 <_IO_puts>:

~$ ls -la /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Jan  9 04:28 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.19.so
~$ readelf -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep system
620: 00040190    56 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 __libc_system@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
~$ readelf -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep IO_puts
203: 00065650   421 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 _IO_puts@@GLIBC_2.0
~$ ls -l /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1754876 May 26  2016 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
```

Machine 2:

```
~$ objdump -d /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep system
00040310 <__libc_system>:

~$ objdump -d /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep "IO_puts>"
000657e0 <_IO_puts>:

~$ ls -la /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Jan  9 04:28 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.19.so

~$ readelf -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep system
620: 00040310    56 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 __libc_system@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
~$ readelf -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep IO_puts
203: 000657e0   421 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 _IO_puts@@GLIBC_2.0
~$ ls -l /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1754876 Feb 25  2015 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
```

Any insight here will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Patches applied to libc by a vendor won't necessarily change its version number. Are your two systems running the same operating system and the same revision of the package that provides libc?

Comment: There are also kernel and compiler options which do similar things to make the system more secure.  This is meant to protect people from what you probably have in mind.  I don't see any reason a non-hacker would check this.

Comment: @Fox : both are glibc 2.19 versions built in a prebuilt machine image. Even the symbol table has same offsets as mentione in objdump. Added more details.

Comment: @Mark , Yeah the operating system is same on both and both have glibc 2.19
Julie , I missed mentioning it is in regard with a challenge.

Comment: Can you include the output of `ls -l /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so` ?

Comment: Mark, I just checked the versions on the VMs are Ubuntu 14.04.01 and 14.04.03. Verified it is same for same releases which is causing the difference.
@Fox , Thanks Mark for inputs, here it is due to different os releases. And ASLR, I believe comes into picture while loading the linked libraries to load them at different locations in different execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> same version libc have same offsets

Close, but not quite.  The same version of any library **could** have the same offsets if compiled by the same compiler, using the same optimization routines, targeting the same platform, using the same rules on instruction set extensions.  So for example, if one OS maintainer compiles libc with gcc version 5.4, another uses gcc version 6.3, and another uses clang, it's entirely possible that no offsets may match.

As shared objects (.so) are dynamically linked position-independent code, it makes no difference under the hood: the functions that are called from a library that has been linked should behave as expected.

On the other hand, if you've installed a pre-built libc from the same repo on 2 VMs with identical CPU configuration, then I'd say it bears further investigation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just checked the versions on the VMs are Ubuntu  14.04.01 and 14.04.03. Verified it is same for same releases.